# Multiple outer joins semantics

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, outer-join

Some SQL code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tab1 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 tab2 ON (tab1.fg = tab2.fg)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 tab4 ON (tab1.ss = tab4.ss)
   INNER JOIN table3 tab3 ON (tab4.xya = tab3.xya)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 tab5 ON (tab4.kk = tab5.kk)
```

I know what different types of JOINs do, but what I'd like to know is: for each JOIN, which table assumes the role of the "LEFT" table? Will `table1` always have the role of the "LEFT" table?

Comment: [Here is a good visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Looks cool, but I'm still not sure what are the semantics in case of multiple joins.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are processed in top-to-bottom order, with the joins all associating to the "whole" of the prior FROM clause.

All things being equal:

- tab1 is the mandatory partner for the OUTER JOIN with the optional partner tab2
- the above is the mandatory partner for the OUTER JOIN with the optional partner tab4
- the above and tab4 are both mandatory partners in the INNER JOIN
- the above is the mandatory partner for the OUTER JOIN with the optional partner tab5

However, the problem with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tab1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab1.fg = tab2.fg
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 tab4 ON tab1.ss = tab4.ss
INNER JOIN table3 tab3 ON tab4.xya = tab3.xya
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 tab5 ON tab4.kk = tab5.kk
```

Is that the INNER JOIN with table3 uses a condition that REQUIRES tab4 to get involved, making it virtually a mandatory link to retain records from the left part, so in total tab1/tab4/tab3 have to successfully join, with tab2 and tab5 optional.

Comment: What do you mean by "All things being equal"?  What would be an example in this case of not "all things being equal"?

Comment: Does the order of columns in the equality comparison matter at all?